# .NET 5 - spinning up an MS SQL docker container for integration tests

Tags: sql-server, docker, integration-testing, .net-5

I have a .NET 5 solution with a services project that contains a series of repositories responsible for saving / loading data from a database (mainly via EFCore).

I am writing some integration tests for this project so would like to test the actions against a real SQL Server database.

Using docker is it possible to have the process of running tests spin up and teardown an SQL Server docker container and if so how might one go about it?

Currently I am just running docker-compose up manually to spin up a container and then running dotnet test which has a connection string pointing to the docker instance and generates dummy data ready for the tests.

I've looked at creating a Dockerfile for the test project however by my understanding a dockerfile is used to generate an image of a project, and I don't actually want generate a docker image, I just want run tests against a docker container that exists purely for the scope of the tests.

Comment: If the answer was "yes" would that answer your question? What are you *really* asking here?

Comment: well... if yes, how might you go about it?

Comment: I think your question might be too broad that needs to focus.

Answer (score 5):

I've managed to implement what I require using a great nuget package called dotnet testcontainers ( https://github.com/HofmeisterAn/dotnet-testcontainers )

This allows me to spin up a standard sql server docker image from within c# code, import my sql scripts, and then afterwards it all gets teared down.

I am using xUnit for testing so I use the CollectionDefinition principle to spin up a container once and then dispose of it afterwards.

**DatabaseFixture.cs**

```cs
public class DatabaseFixture : IDisposable
{
    private const int _hostPort = 1434;
    private const int _containerPort = 1433;
    private const string _databasePassword = "localdevpassword#123";
    private const string _databaseUser = "sa";

    private string _myDbContext_ConnectionString =>
        $"Server=tcp:localhost,{_hostPort};Database=MyDbContext;user id={_databaseUser};password={_databasePassword};";
    
    public TestcontainersContainer Container { get; private set; }
    public MyDbContext MyDb { get; private set; }
    
    public DatabaseFixture()
    {
        InitContainerTest();
        
        var myDbContextContextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>()
            .UseSqlServer(_myDbContext_ConnectionString)
            .Options;
            
        MyDb = new MyDbContext(myDbContextContextOptions );

        // Seed the database if required
        
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Container.StopAsync();
        Container.CleanUpAsync();
    }
    
    private void InitContainerTest()
    {
        
        var outputConsumer = Consume.RedirectStdoutAndStderrToStream(new MemoryStream(), new MemoryStream());
        var waitStrategy = Wait.ForUnixContainer().UntilMessageIsLogged(outputConsumer.Stdout, "INIT_COMPLETE");

        var containerBuilder = new TestcontainersBuilder<TestcontainersContainer>()
            .WithImage("mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest")
            .WithPortBinding(_hostPort, _containerPort)
            .WithEnvironment("ACCEPT_EULA", "true")
            .WithEnvironment("SA_PASSWORD", _databasePassword)
            .WithBindMount(Path.GetFullPath("sql"), "/scripts/")
            .WithCommand("/bin/bash", "-c", "/scripts/init.sh")
            .WithOutputConsumer(outputConsumer)
            .WithWaitStrategy(waitStrategy);

        Container = containerBuilder.Build();
        
        var task = Container.StartAsync();
        task.WaitAndUnwrapException();
    }
}
```

**DatabaseCollection.cs**

```cs
[CollectionDefinition("Database collection")]
public class DatabaseCollection : ICollectionFixture<DatabaseFixture>
{
    // This class has no code, and is never created. Its purpose is simply
    // to be the place to apply [CollectionDefinition] and all the
    // ICollectionFixture<> interfaces.
}
```

**UserServiceTests.cs**

```cs
[Collection("Database collection")]
public class UserServiceTests
{
    private readonly UserService _sut;
    private readonly DatabaseFixture _databaseFixture;

    public UserServiceTests(DatabaseFixture databaseFixture)
    {
        _databaseFixture = databaseFixture;
        _sut = new UserService(_databaseFixture.MyDb);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task GetUserCompany_ShouldReturnCompanyId_WhenUserIdFound()
    {
        // Arrange
        var faker = new Faker<Thing>();
        faker.RuleFor(e => e.UserId, f => Guid.NewGuid());
        faker.RuleFor(e => e.CompanyId, f => Guid.NewGuid());
        var thing = faker.Generate();
        _databaseFixture.MyDb.Things.Add(thing);
        await _databaseFixture.MyDb.SaveChangesAsync();
        
        // Act
        var actualOutput = await _sut.GetCompanyIdFromUserId(thing.UserId);
        
        // Assert
        actualOutput.Should().Be(thing.CompanyId);
    }       
}
```

**Things that need some work**

<strike>I will need to manually add a delay after Container.StartAsync() to allow the database scripts to run.</strike>

I now wait for the container stdout to output "INIT_COMPLETE" which is the final line of my init.sh file that gets copied across. I also now run the StartAsync() method from within the DatabaseFixture using a slight hack to allow for async code to be run from within a none async method.

```
var task = Container.StartAsync();
task.WaitAndUnwrapException();
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this solution. I'm getting error: can't login for 'sa' ! What is the content of scripts folder and init.sh file ?